# Cannot resolve dependencies for @nestjs/swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nest, nestjs-swagger

I am trying to install `@nestjs/swagger` using `npm i @nestjs/swagger` as per documentation.

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^9.0.0" from @nestjs/swagger@6.0.3
```

Any idea what is the issue?I can see that the package was last published a few hours ago, not sure if related.

Comment: A peer dependency is a dependency that you need to have in your package.json, not included in the package itself. You may try to install or update @nestjs/common in order to match the version

Comment: obviously I have tried that

Comment: What's the version in your package.json?

Answer (score 3):

`npm-check-updates "/nestjs*/" -u` and `nest update` solved this